# how can I listen to a certain port using Java?

Tags: java, sockets, websocket

Sorry I'm asking this, but I'm new to socket programming in general.
I'd like to read all the data that comes from a certain port, say 8080.
how can I do it? can you give me a simple example, on which I can build a solid understanding?

Thank you!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html

`ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8080);`

Comment: This answers the question in the title but not the question in the text.

Comment: @EJP feel free to write your own answer

Answer (score 0):

This listens from a port, gets the socket, creates a reader from the stream and prints every line that comes from the socket:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);

Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println("Line from socket: "+line);
}
```

From there I'm sure you can go on by yourself